# Displaying created case numbers on screen flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows, screen-flow

I have a screen flow used to create cases to the trading department.  The flow functions as it should, however on the final screen, I want to give a reference to the case numbers that were created.  I'm able to display the ID's that were created, but I fear that I'm going to get push-back on that.  Since flow is still fairly new to my skillset, it's difficult to explain the process outside of a screenshot of the whole thing.  Please let me know what you would need to see to be able to assist.  The final screen that displays the Id's is:

You're all set!

For your reference, below the following cases were created:

```
   ID('s) of created Sleeved Cases:  
   {!Collection_SleevedCases}

   ID('s) of created non-Sleeved Cases:  
   {!Collection_NonSleevedCases}
```

You can now close this window!

Comment: have the Flow do a Get Records on the created Cases to fetch CaseNumber

Comment: I apologize is this is a silly follow up question, but how would I go about obtaining only the cases that were created?  In my "Get Records" element, I don't have a way match an Id from the record collection of the cases that were created.

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work by doing a loop of the created cases and assigning the case numbers of those to a text variable and passed that variable to a text template.  On the final screen, I'm referencing the text template instead of the collection.